# WordPress Tags and archives are not showing the post upon clicking

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I open any post on my blog, it shows the complete post with the related tags below. When I click the tags it redirects to the parent post. Why is this happening? Will post code soon.

Here is the link, please have a look.

[please click here](http://adpublishing.net/drdevin/can-chiropractors-help-with-your-carpal-tunnel-syndrome/)
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but you'd get more answers if you asked your question intelligibly. I took a look at the link. I think I understand your issue, but it's impossible to say what's going on unless you post the relevant code from your template.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John: it's hard to tell what's going on without looking at your code. I suggest making an `archive.php` file or a more dynamic `index.php`.